# How to make simulation of Computer assembly

Tags: java, animation

I just want to ask if you have a recommendations regarding to Computer Simulation workspace assembly.

I want to make a software just like [these](http://vimeo.com/15588533), but the problem is that I don't know how to start. What package/library do I need to make a software like that using Java programming?

Comment: That's not programming, that's 3D animation. It can be quite technical as well, but it doesn't *usually* wander into the realm of programming (at least until you hit shader programming or start scripting your environment).

Comment: I want to implement sir a custom assembly of computers at runtime is it possible in java?

Comment: I voted to close as this question is fairly unspecific. @Alvin: not knowing where to start is an indicator for having chosen the wrong project. Maybe you should start with something else?

Comment: @Alvin: yes, it's possible using Java3D, but you'll have to do lot's of modelling in 3D software anyway, so it's probably easier/faster/better to do the whole thing in the 3D tools anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tools to create those videos, like 3D Studio in http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/
Also there are video tools for post-production video like Adobe Premiere and a few other free tools.

You really should forget programming to do that... unless you want to be a 3D programmer. If you don't even know what Java or other can do, just forget it. Use existing tools to do that.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey, thank you, I think I should go for 3D MAX to generate object and just add it to JPanel.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, this simulation does not make in some programming language, but in some software for making 3D animation, like 3D MAX, or something like that.